# Swift protocol used as type in method not accepting instances of same protocol

Tags: swift, generics, protocols

I've encountered a problem with a method which I cannot explain. Here is some test code which shows the problem:

```
protocol Base {}
protocol Extended: Base {}

struct Instance:Extended {}

let anInstance = Instance()
let instanceOfBase = anInstance as Base
let instanceOfExtended = anInstance as Extended

func aMethod<T:Base>(_ instance:T) {}

aMethod(anInstance)
aMethod(instanceOfBase) // Error - Cannot invoke 'aMethod' with an argument list of type '(Base)'
aMethod(instanceOfExtended) // Error - Cannot invoke 'aMethod' with an argument list of type '(Extended)'
```

According to the Apple doco I've read on protocols, generics, etc. `aMethod()` should accept any object that conforms to the `Base` protocol. Yet it rejects both instances where I have cast them to either `Base` or `Extended`.

Can anyone explain this?

Also:

```
func aMethod2(_ instance:Base) {}
aMethod2(anInstance)
aMethod2(instanceOfBase)
aMethod2(instanceOfExtended)
```

Works fine so the difference seems to be whether the `instance` argument is based (excuse the pun) on `Base` or `<T:Base>`.

For anyone questioning why I would declare a generic here. The original code looked like this:

```
func addViewController<T:ModelObject>(_ stack:inout [UIViewController],
                               object:T?,
                               controller:DetailsViewController<T>?,
                               storyboardId:String) {...
```

As you can see, I want to constrain several arguments to the same type. Hence the use of a generic rather than just specifying base.

Comment: This is because [protocols don't conform to themselves](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33112559/2976878).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## `T` is a constraint on a concrete type

`<T:Base>` is a constraint on the placeholder type `T`. `T` must be a concrete type (a class, enum or struct such as `Instance`) that conforms to the `Base` protocol. The placeholder type `T` cannot be the `Base` protocol.

`aMethod<T:Base>(:)` must be called with a variable that is of a type that conforms to the `Base` protocol at compile time. `aMethod<T:Base>(:)` cannot be called with a variable that is only known to be of type `Base`.

The following line of code instantiates a variable named `anInstance` that is of struct type `Instance`.

```
let anInstance = Instance()
```

`aMethod(anInstance)` compiles because `anInstance` is of a concrete type `Instance` that conforms to the `Base` protocol.

The following line of code instantiates a variable named `instanceOfBase` that is of protocol type `Base`.

```
let instanceOfBase: Instance = anInstance as Base
```

`aMethod(instanceOfBase)` does not compile because `instanceOfBase` is not of a concrete type that conforms to the `Base` protocol. It is of the protocol type `Base`.

Here is another snippet that fails to illustrate the issue. In this case the `base` argument is only known to be of the protocol type `Base`.

```
func aMethod(base: Base) {
    aMethod(base) // Cannot invoke 'aMethod' with an argument list of type '(Base)'
}
```

Comment: Yet both `instanceOfBase is Base` and `instanceOfExtended is Base` are true. So if `instanceOfBase` is a `Base`, why can I not pass it to a method that accepts an argument that confirms to `Base` according to the generics documentation?

Comment: But shouldn't the compiler see `instanceOfBase` as 'an instance of something that conforms to Base' and therefore pass it because the method accepts things that 'conform to Base'? This sounds like it's deciding to treat `Base` as a concrete type, which it isn't. When it should be treating it effectively as `Any<Base>` or something like that.

Comment: I interpret `<T:Base>` to be a constraint on the Type `T`. `T` must be a concrete type that conforms to the `Base` protocol. `T` cannot be any type that conforms to the `Base` protocol.

Comment: This is limitation of protocols and generics in Swift currently.

Comment: Nuts. Java is way better in this area.

Comment: I come from a C# background and what you are doing seems like it should work to the C# developer in me. However, I've been wrestling with this lately and am slowly learning how it works.

Comment: Agreed. I think this will improve in future Swift versions.

Comment: Swift is compiled to machine instructions so you get great performance at the cost of flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, I don't really get why you're doing this.

Let's say:

- you want `aMethod` to accept any instance that conforms to `Base` protocol, then you can just make it `func aMethod(_ instance: Base) {}`
- You want preserve type information inside the function then you use the generic method but pass in an instance of a concrete implementation of the protocol.

Please note that `func aMethod<T:Base>(_ instance:T) {}` means it's expecting an instance of *type* `T` that conforms `Base`. Neither `Base` or `Extended` is a valid *type*.

What you're doing here is using generics without its power...Which, IMHO, doesn't make sense. Unless you can provide a more realistic scenario?

Comment: The more realistic example was `func aMethod<T:Base>(_ instance:T, anotherThing:SomeType<T>)`. Essentially in my original code I had several method arguments which where either of type 'T' or where of a generic type. I wanted to ensure that the compiler would validate that all arguments used the same type.

Comment: For example, if I had a type `MyT:Base` then I wanted the function to look like `aMethod(_ instance:MyT, anotherThing:SomeType<MyT>)` but as I have a number of classes that implement `Base`, generics seemed like the answer.

Comment: The reason why I'm using protocols like this is that there can be a number of implementations and I want to declare things based on the protocols to code that doesn't care about which implementation it has been passed. It'a also a good idea from the point of view of testing.

Comment: @drekka Right. My suggestion would be if you can't write `aMethod(_ instance: Base, anotherThing: SomeType<Base>)` or `aMethod<T: Base>(_ instance: T, anotherThing: SomeType<T>)` then you've reached the point where swift generics can't provide at this moment. Check https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/GenericsManifesto.md for further development. Also, **type erase** may help with a workaround.

Comment: Thanks. Have already tried type erasure. Worked in a playground, but in the larger context of my app it failed to solve the problems I was trying to solve. It's really good for effectively wrapping an associated type in a generic so you can use it as a type, but doesn't solve the basic problem of wanting to declare a variable to be an generic with an unknown type. ie. Type<?>, or Type<Any>.